# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'time_recorded' in Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an api endpoint that passes a variable which is used to make a call in the database. For some reason it cannot run the query yet the syntax is correct. My code is below.

```
@app.route('/api/update/<lastqnid>')
def check_new_entries(lastqnid):
    result = Trades.query.filter_by(id=lastqnid).first()
    new_entries = Trades.query.filter(Trades.time_recorded > result.time_recorded).all()
```

The id field is:

```
id = db.Column(db.String,default=lambda: str(uuid4().hex), primary_key=True)
```

I have tried `filter` instead of `filter_by` and it does not work. When I remove the `filter_by(id=lastqnid)` it works. What could be the reason it is not running the query?

The trades table am querying from is

```
class Trades(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String,default=lambda: str(uuid4().hex), primary_key=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False)
    time_recorded = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique=False)
```

Comment: You are showing what you are doing that is causing the error, but what we are not seeing is the code related to the error. What is `time_recorded` and where is it used?

Comment: If you are doing something like `result.time_recorded` without checking if you actually found anything, like `if result == None`, it may very well produce this error. Albeit, I'm just assuming from the information you have given...

Comment: Added table that I was querying from

Comment: Please locate the line that is producing the error.

Comment: Error arises from new_entries = Trades.query.filter(Trades.time_recorded > result.time_recorded).all()

Comment: When the `result.time_recorded` is read, it returns an error since it is `NoneType`. That means the query is not going through. When I replace 
`id=lastqnid` with `id='asshbfjjjdjbjdbgdv12dgf'` , it works. When I print the variable, I can see it in the console, but when I pass it, it fails to be read.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you seem to be having is not checking if you found anything before using your result

```
@app.route('/api/update/<lastqnid>')
def check_new_entries(lastqnid):
    result = Trades.query.filter_by(id=lastqnid).first()
    # Here result may very well be None, so we can make an escape here
    if result == None:
        # You may not want to do exactly this, but this is an example
        print("No Trades found with id=%s" % lastqnid)
        return redirect(request.referrer)
    new_entries = Trades.query.filter(Trades.time_recorded > result.time_recorded).all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But am querying a record that I am sure exists in the db ( I have even inspected the db and it is there) yet the query is not working for some reason

Comment: Well then I assume there is something wrong with `lastqnid`. Did you add the print statement to check what it is?

Comment: Yes, it is the output of the uuid4().hex . Actually when I take the value of `lastqnid` and manually place it in the query, it works as expected.

Comment: So what was the output? Are you 100% positive it is a string? What does `type(lastqnid)` say?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `print(request.url)`?

Comment: Yes, output on cmd is `<class 'str'>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173947/discussion-between-pax-vobiscum-and-patrick-mutuku).